# Don't echo specific error message when executing mysql command in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have to execute following mysql command  via bash scripting:

```
drop table $tablename \; | mysql -uusername -ppassword $dbname
```

This command is executed a lot of times, but the problem is that `$tablename` can be dropped before the command is run. And when it is dropped already, I get following message on my command prompt:

```
ERROR 1051 (42S02) at line 1: Unknown table 'tablename'
database table tablename, not found
```

Is there a way to filter this error message out so I don't get spammed with this?

EDIT: And is there a similar workaround like `IF EXISTS` for when creating tables? For preventing getting the following `Table already exists`.

Ok, it's `IF NOT EXISTS` thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`if exists`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html):

```
 drop table if exists $tablename
```

From the documentation:

> Use IF EXISTS to prevent an error from occurring for tables that do not exist. A NOTE is generated for each nonexistent table when using IF EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [DROP TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html) syntax, you'll see that there's a `IF EXISTS` clause that's designed to deal with the fact that the table might not exist.

As such, using...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tablename \; | mysql -uusername -ppassword $dbname
```

...will resolve this issue.

Answer (score -2):

I also discovered that `... 2>/dev/null` can be used. Which will write the output to /dev/null, and outputs nothing on the command prompt...

```
drop table $tablename \; | mysql -uusername -ppassword $dbname 2>/dev/null
```

/dev/null is called the black hole